# How do I add a background image for the webpage in springboot project using custom CSS with JSP in Spring tool suite?

Tags: css, spring-boot, jsp, background-image, static-files

I have been trying to add a background image to the web page of my Spring Boot project, but I think it's not configured properly and don't know exactly where to include the custom CSS and the image in the project directory. Where can I include the custom CSS and the image project directory?

Is there anything to be added into application properties?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a background image to webpage irrespective of the framework you are using as it is html specific. Just ensure that the image is present on the mentioned path.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-image: url("images/background.jpg");
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1-spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reservation...
2-spring.datasource.username=root...
3-spring.datasource.password=   .....

4- spring.jpa.show-sql=true...

5-spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsps/...
6-spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp...
7-logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO...

8-server.servlet.context-path=/flightreservation...

9-spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false...

10-spring.resources.static-locations=/static/              .........this is my application.properties

Comment: The background image is in the directory src/main/resources ... under this directory i have included the folder  1-Static,  under static there is a) CSS b) images and c) JS sub-folders. Background image is located in the b) images.

Comment: Just inspect elements devtools in browser and check what path it is taking currently...based on that you can make changes and find out the correct path.

Comment: I'm new to this and being stuck at this making me lose hope. Unable to upload the screenshot of the directory so that you could help me rectify it.

Comment: Tried posting the screenshot of the directory and .jsp but this is what happening when i tried to upload the screenshot------ An error occured when uploading the image:

Answer (score 0):

I also got encounter with the same problem maybe this would work for some people so i uploaded my solution as well.
For adding background image this is same as we did in css or html but just make sure that your image folder is placed in main/resources/static folder.
then you can use background by add below html and css code.

html :

```
<div class="back">
</div>
```

css :

```
.back{
    background-image: url('./image/background.jpg');
    height:100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```